# Why is h silent in honor but not in hone

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

*Hone* and *honor* both start with "hon" but h is silent in honor but not in hone.

I googled it and searched everywhere but didn't find the answer. Can you help me please?

Comment: Honor comes from French; hone from Germanic.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508916/was-help-pronounced-starting-with-a-vowel-sound) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23396/is-the-history-of-h-dropping-in-english-in-any-way-related-to-the-silent-h-of-fr).

Answer (score 3):

Etymology, origin and usage come into play, but how the pronounciation evolved through the years is not always clear as explained in the following extract from [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/explore/words-with-silent-h) :

> H is silent in many English words, for various reasons.
>
> Sometimes it is because of the word's derivation (e.g. messiah from
>   Hebrew or rhapsody from Greek); sometimes it is as a result of elision
>   (e.g. shepherd, exhaust).
>
> The words hour and honest come from French,  and in these cases English took over the French pronunciation as well
>   as the word. Not all such words that have come into English from
>   French still have a silent h, however.
>
> ***Over the centuries we have come to pronounce the h in words like horrible, hospital, host, human, and
>   humour.***

***[Honor](https://www.etymonline.com/word/honor)*** derives from from Anglo-French honour, Old French onor, honor, but:

> The initial h in honest, honor, etc., is merely etymological, the sound having already disappeared when the word came into ME use. (Century Dictionary).

***[Hone (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hone#etymonline_v_12137)*** appears to have preserved the original Germanic pronunciation:

> Old English han "a stone, rock, (boundary) stone," from Proto-Germanic *haino (source also of Old Norse hein "hone").

Comment: Until recently we would say **an hotel** (from the French *hôtel*) but I don't hear this now. Although many Brits "drop their aitches" there some who exaggerate unneeded ***h***aitches in mockery.